# Show that $\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx= \frac{ \pi /n}{\sin(\pi /n)}$ , where $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Using residues, try the contour below with $R \rightarrow  \infty$ and  $$\lim_{R \rightarrow  \infty }  \int_0^R  \frac{1}{1+r^n}  dr \rightarrow \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{1+x^n}  dx$$

[image]

I've attempted the residue summation, but my sum did not converge.

Comment: The sum will only have one term (there is only one pole inside the contour).

Comment: I thought it would have more than one, because the poles at n=1,2,3,... are each at a certain angle from the real axis, however with each n the contour angle changes as well, keeping the poles within the contour.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The integral of
$$
\int_\gamma\frac1{1+z^n}\mathrm{d}z\tag{1}
$$
on the outgoing ray on the real axis tends to
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
On the incoming ray parallel to $e^{2\pi i/n}$, the integral tends to
$$
-e^{2\pi i/n}\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
$$
For $n\ge2$, the integral on the circular arc vanishes. Therefore,
$$
\int_\gamma\frac1{1+z^n}\mathrm{d}z
=\left(1-e^{2\pi i/n}\right)\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}
$$
There is one singularity contained in $\gamma$ at $z_0=e^{\pi i/n}$. The residue of $\frac1{1+x^n}$ at $z_0$ is $\frac1{nz_0^{n-1}}=-\frac{z_0}{n}$. Thus,
$$
2\pi i\left(-\frac{e^{\pi i/n}}{n}\right)
=\left(1-e^{2\pi i/n}\right)\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}
$$
which resolves by division to
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)}\tag{6}
$$
For $n=1$, the integral diverges and $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi)}=\frac\pi0$.

Comment: If we consider the case where n = 7, this method fails?  I am doing it for this particular case and I am getting a negative in front of the division and thus I am off by a $-1$ factor.

Comment: It is unclear where you are getting the negative. $(6)$ says that $$\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^7}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi/7}{\sin(\pi/7)}$$

Comment: @robjohn How did you find the residue of $\frac{1}{1+z^n}$ at $z_0$?

Comment: @Twink: $z_0$ is a simple root of $1+z^n$. To find the coefficient of $\frac1{z-z_0}$ in the expansion of $\frac1{1+z^n}$, we multiply by $z-z_0$ and take the limit as $z\to z_0$. That is, using L'Hôpital, $$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{1+z^n}=\frac1{nz_0^{n-1}}=-\frac{z_0}n$$

Answer (score 3):

Supposed that you have no idea of how to do integration over the complex, this problem can also be solved neatly.

Denote $t:=x^n$, and we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{1+x^n} &= \frac1n\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac1n-1}}{1+t}\mathrm{d} t\\
&=\frac1n\:\mathrm{B}(\frac1n, 1-\frac1n) \\
&=\frac1n\:\Gamma(\frac1n)\cdot\Gamma(1-\frac1n)\\
&=\frac{\pi/n}{\sin \pi/n}
\end{align}

Here we used a famous result, $\displaystyle\Gamma(z)\cdot\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}} \quad (0<\mathrm{Re}(z)<1)$