# Contour integral along a straight line - why does this simple practice problem fail to be simple?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

> Use the residue theorem to compute:$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$By using the contour that goes first from $0\to r$ along the real axis ($\gamma_1$), then in an arc from $r\to r\exp(\frac{2}{3}\pi i)$ ($\gamma_2$), then in a straight line from $r\exp(\frac{2}{3}\pi i)\to0$ ($\gamma_3$), taking limits as $r\to\infty$.

Firstly we need to show that the integral along this contour is equivalent to the integral along the real axis, as $r\to\infty$, so it first must be shown that:

$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z=0$$

This part is straightforward: noticing that the arc, when cubed, is transformed to a circle of radius $r^3$ - missing the point $(r^3,0)$ - and adding $1$ to all values on this circle shifts the circle such that the smallest value of $|z^3+1|$ is $r^3-1$:

$$0\le\lim_{r\to\infty}\left|\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,dz\right|\le\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{2}{3}\pi r\cdot\sup_{\gamma_2}\frac{1}{|z^3+1|}\le\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{2}{3}\pi r\cdot\frac{1}{r^3-1}=0$$

So the contour $\gamma_2$ is accounted for. Sadly, using the same estimation trick on the straight line segment $\gamma_3$ fails, since the maximum value of $(z^3+1)^{-1}$ on $\gamma_3$ is just $1$, which fails to give a limit to zero. Deciding to crack the integral by hand, I proceeded:

$$\begin{align}\int_{\gamma_3}\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z&=\int_r^0\frac{\exp\frac{2}{3}\pi i}{(t\exp\frac{2}{3}\pi i)^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\&=-\exp\frac{2}{3}\pi i\int_0^r\frac{1}{t^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\end{align}$$

And got immediately stuck. According to Wolfram Alpha, the antiderivative does exist but it is not at all clear that as $r\to\infty$, the integral goes to $0$. Besides, this is a practice problem; although university level, I doubt one has to crack a very tricky antiderivative and an unclear limit. What am I doing wrong? As far as I understand it, in order for the residue theorem to be of any use, the contour integral enclosing the singularity must first be shown to evaluate to the integral along the real axis.

Comment: Notice that the integral over $\gamma_3$ is a multiple of your original integral.

Comment: @pax - thank you, that solves it immediately!

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question by adding at the beginning **instead of at the end** how you have solved your issue : as it is at present, it's hard to a (new) reader to understand what was the question...

Comment: @JeanMarie I've placed it at the end now, thank you. I thought the common practice was to do the opposite, but clearly I was mistaken

Comment: The key here is that the $\frac{1}{z^3 + 1}$ part is the same, but the $dz$ part is not the same (and is off by a multiple $e^{2\pi i / 3})$. Always be careful with $u$-substitutions when you're trying to relate two integrals.

Comment: 1) This question is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367801). 2) Thanks for having taken into account my remark.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the link to the correct solution ... I spent far longer on this question than I should have done, but at least it's done and I know it's right.

Comment: [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx) should handle this question. [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216) uses contour integration.

Comment: @robjohn Incredible! Thank you for this, I will study it. It is not clear to me how the keyhole contour is parametrised - is it like a Hankel contour?

Comment: The circular parts can be parametrized as $re^{it}$ for fixed $r$ and $t$ just inside $[0,2\pi]$, and the linear parts are just lines. It shouldn't matter exactly how, but if you really need it, I can work out the parameterization.

Comment: I gather one limits it as tight as possible, with the keyhole radius being made less than $\varepsilon$ - is this right? As far exact details, that's fine - as soon as I finally thrashed this one out I wondered if one could use contour techniques for the general integral, and it's been very helpful to see your answer @robjohn

Comment: Here is how I usually specify contours, using $\epsilon\lt r\lt R$: $$\overbrace{\left[\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2},\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2}\right](1,0)+(0,\epsilon)}^\text{line over the real axis}\cup\overbrace{Re^{i\left[\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/R),2\pi-\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/R)\right]}}^\text{large circle}\\\cup\underbrace{\left[\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2},\sqrt{r^2-\epsilon^2}\right](1,0)+(0,-\epsilon)}_\text{line under the real axis}\cup\underbrace{re^{i\left[2\pi-\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/r),\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/r)\right]}}_\text{small circle}$$ each $[a,b]$ range is a range of real numbers between the two values.

Answer (score 1):

For any students confused as I was, the answer is simpler than I first thought (credit to the users [Pax](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/47926/pax), [Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie)): the integral I struggled to evaluate at the bottom is in fact just a constant multiple of the original integral, as $r\to\infty$.

With this in mind, my answer comes out as (where $\gamma=\gamma_0+\gamma_1+\gamma_2$):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z&=I-\exp\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi i\right)I\\&=2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^3+1},\,\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}\pi i\right)\right)\\&=2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{3}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i\right)\\\implies I&=2\pi i\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i\right)}{1-\exp\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi i\right)}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{3}\cdot\frac{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{3}\cdot\frac{1+i}{-3+\sqrt{3}i}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{3}\cdot\frac{-4\sqrt{3}i}{12}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{3}\cdot\frac{-i}{\sqrt{3}}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\\\therefore\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\end{align}$$

Which is the correct answer as corroborated by other posts on this site.

About the residue:

Let $\zeta=\exp\frac{1}{3}\pi i$, the cube root of $-1$ that is present in the contour's interior. As this is a simple pole of $\frac{1}{z^3+1}$, the following limit finds the residue.

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^3+1},\exp\frac{1}{3}\pi i\right)=\lim_{z\to\zeta}\frac{z-\zeta}{z^3+1}=\lim_{z\to\zeta}\frac{1}{z^2+\zeta z+\zeta^2}=\frac{1}{3\zeta^2}=\frac{1}{3}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i\right)$$

Where one step was achieved by simple polynomial division.

Comment: How did you got this residue?

Comment: I wrote it down at the bottom of my post, if you missed it. If there's anything you'd like me to clarify, I'll do so @Lac