# Why $\lim\limits_{R \to +\infty} \int_{[0,Re^{i2\pi/n}]}\frac{1}{1+z^n}dz$ = $e^{i2\pi/n}$ $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

Why $\lim\limits_{R \to +\infty}  \int_{[0,Re^{i2\pi/n}]}\frac{1}{1+z^n}dz$ = $e^{i2\pi/n}$ $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$

(The integration is on the ray: ${[0,Re^{i2\pi/n}]}$)

As it is shown in the following topic:
[Show that $\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx= \frac{ \pi /n}{\sin(\pi /n)}$ , where $n$ is a positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/show-that-int-0-infty-frac11xn-dx-frac-pi-n-sin-pi-n-wh?lq=1) in number (3).

Comment: Just parametrise the ray by $z = e^{2\pi i /n}\cdot x$. Note the relation between $dz$ and $dx$ and between $z^n$ and $x^n$.

Comment: But by parametrising the ray by $z = e^{i(2 \pi)/n} . x$, x goes from 0 to 1, i need it to go from 0 to R in order to apply the limit and obtain the integrale of $1/(1+x^n)$ from 0 to +$\infty$.

And when i try $z = e^{i(2 \pi)/n} . x * \frac1 R$, the second term of the equality doesn't appear easily..

Comment: No, to reach the point $Re^{2\pi i/n}$, we need $x = R$ in that parametrisation.

Comment: Ahh you're right! you used :

h(t) = $ \frac {b-t} {b-a} z_{A} +  \frac {b-t} {b-a} z_{B} $ to parametrize a segment [AB]...

Thank you !