# Evaluating integral (comes from a bigger problem in statistics)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Let $\alpha, \beta>0$ be parameters. I wish to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x-1} e^{-\beta x} dx.$$

I managed to reduce this problem when $\alpha$ is integer by using
$$\frac{x^\alpha}{x-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{\alpha} x^{j-1}.$$

So the question is how to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x-1} e^{-\beta x} dx.$$
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The integral diverges due to the singularity at $x=1$.

Comment: The p.v. integral is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2851656).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral of interest, $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta x}}{x-1}\,dx $ diverges due to the singularity at $x=1$.  However, the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral exists and can be expressed as

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta x}}{x-1}\,dx &=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-\beta x}}{x-1}\,dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty \frac{e^{-\beta x}}{x-1}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=e^{-\beta }\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{-\beta}^{-\beta\epsilon}\frac{e^{- x}}{x}\,dx+\int_{\beta\epsilon}^\infty \frac{e^{- x}}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=-e^{-\beta}\text{Ei}(\beta)
\end{align}$$

in terms of the Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(x)\equiv -\text{PV}\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$.

If $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha\ge 1$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha e^{-\beta x}}{x-1}\,dx&=(-1)^{\alpha+1} \frac{d^\alpha}{d\beta^\alpha}\left(e^{-\beta}\text{Ei}(\beta)\right)\\\\
&=-e^{-\beta}\text{Ei}(\beta)+\sum_{m=1}^\alpha \frac{(m-1)!}{\beta^m}
\end{align}$$

Comment: did you assume that $\alpha$ is an integer?

Comment: Hi Mark ! Long time. How are you ? Cheers

Comment: @Szeto Yes, I wrote explicitly "If $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha\ge 1$."

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude.  It has been a while.  I am still alive and doing fine.   And you?

Comment: The same for *still alive* only. Nice to see you.

Comment: The last line should be
$$-e^{-\beta} \operatorname{Ei} (\beta) +
 \sum_{m = 1}^\alpha \frac {(m - 1)!} {\beta^m}.$$

Comment: @maxim Thank you.  I've edited.

Comment: There shouldn't be a $(-1)^{\alpha + 1}$ factor though.

Comment: @maxim Indeed.  And thank you again!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use differentiation and 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha} \, dx}{x-1} = \pi \csc(\pi (\alpha + 1)) \, (-1)^{\alpha}.$$
Let $I(\beta)$ be 
$$I(\beta) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\beta x} \, x^{\alpha} \, dx}{x-1}$$
which leads to
\begin{align}
- I' - I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta x} \, x^{\alpha} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1)}{\beta^{\alpha + 1}}.
\end{align}
The solution of $$I' + I = - \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1)}{\beta^{\alpha + 1}}$$
is $$I(\beta) = c_{1} \, e^{-\beta} + (-1)^{\alpha} \, \Gamma(\alpha + 1) \, e^{-\beta} \, \Gamma(-\alpha, - \beta)$$

The difficulty in this solution is that if $\beta = 0$ then to be a finite solution $R(\alpha) < 0$ must be stated. Other conditions may apply. Continuing without concern of ranges the case would be
$$I(0) = \pi \csc(\pi (\alpha + 1)) \, (-1)^{\alpha} = c_{1} + (-1)^{\alpha} \, \Gamma(\alpha + 1) \, \Gamma(-\alpha, 0)$$
and
$$I(\beta) = (-1)^{\alpha} \, e^{- \beta} \, \left[ \pi \csc(\pi (\alpha + 1)) + \Gamma(\alpha + 1) \, (\Gamma(-\alpha, - \beta) - \Gamma(-\alpha, 0)) \right],$$
where $Re(\alpha) < 0$ and other conditions may apply.

Comment: The p.v. integral in the first formula is real but the rhs isn't.