# Integral of $x^a/(1+x^b)^c$ via residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In one problem I am stuck with an integral that can be mapped to the following form:

$$I = \int_0^\infty dx \ \dfrac{x^a}{(1+x^b)^c}$$

where it can be assumed that $b>0$ and $c>0$. I know that the special case of  $a>0$ and $c=1$ can be solved with the help of the residue theorem (see e.g. [Show that $\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx= \frac{ \pi /n}{\sin(\pi /n)}$ , where $n$ is a positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/show-that-int-0-infty-frac11xn-dx-frac-pi-n-sin-pi-n-wh)), but am not sure how to treat the branch cut that appears for a rational $c$.

Comment: Special case got me... we all have special needs and special cases... can you isolate the branch your interested in and HOW your trying?

Comment: Can you show what work you've done so far? You seem to be stuck in a specific place.

Comment: Your integral is not elementary. Substituting $x = (u/(1- u))^{1/b}$ gives $C \! \int_0^1 u^\alpha (1 - u)^\beta du$, which is a beta function.

Answer (score 1):

As Maxim pointed out the integral is most easily "solved" by mapping it to the beta function.

$$
\begin{align}
I 
&=
\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^a}{(1+x^b)^c} d x
\\ &=
\frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 \frac{d u}{u(1-u)} \left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{\frac{1}{b}} \frac{\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{\frac{a}{b}}}{\left(1 + \frac{u}{1-u}\right)^c}
\\ &=
\frac{1}{b}\int_0^1 d u \ u^{\frac{1+a}{b}-1} \ (1-u)^{1-\frac{1+a}{b}-c}
\\ &\equiv 
\frac{1}{b} B\left(\frac{1+a}{b},2-\frac{1+a}{b}-c\right)
\end{align}
$$

where in the first step we substituted  $x=\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{\frac{1}{b}} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ d x = \frac{d u}{bu(1-u)} \left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{\frac{1}{b}} $. Note that in the case of $c=1$ we can use the reflection formula for gamma functions to turn the beta function in a simple $\csc$.